# PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged is null

Tags: binding, silverlight-4.0, inotifypropertychanged, propertychanged

i am implementing PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged and it's always null. 
property string is right donno where is the problem
here is the code i am using

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

public bool _playerGridVisibility ;
        public bool PlayerGridVisibility
        {
            get { return _playerGridVisibility; }
            set
            {
                _playerGridVisibility = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(Strings.PlayerGridVisibilityString);
            }
```

and in the xaml

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=AdsGridVisibility, Converter={StaticResource VC}}"
        }
```

so can anyone knows the problem ?

Comment: About your way to handle the OnPropertyChanged, you should read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/29/events-and-races/)

Answer (score 4):

One reason this could be happening is if your code does not deal with the original data context.  You might have two copies of the view model and you might be updating the one that is not bound.